# Can someone explain this result?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, slice

There is a demo about go reflection:

```golang
func main() {
        test := []string{"hello"}
        V := reflect.ValueOf(test)
        if reflect.TypeOf(V).Kind() == reflect.Struct{
            fmt.Printf("it's a struct")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("other")
        }
    }
```

and the output is `"it's a struct"`

Answer (score 2):

`V` is a value returned by [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf), so it is of type [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), which is a struct, so `reflect.TypeOf(V).Kind()` is `reflect.Struct`. There's nothing surprising in it.

From the `reflect` package:

```
type Value struct {
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

If you pass `test` itself, its kind will be `reflect.Slice`:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(test).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
    fmt.Printf("it's a slice")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("other")
}
```

This will print (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fGbYBq3D_VH)):

```
it's a slice
```